# How to access Verilog genvar generated instances and their signals

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, xilinx-ise

I need to initialize arrays in generated instances via generate block in Verilog. I'm trying to use the syntax below, however, I get an error as

> External reference foo[0].bar.array[0] remains unresolved.

in Xilinx ISE.

```
    integer i, j;
    initial begin
        // initialization of arrays
        for(i=0; i<(2**7); i=i+1) begin
            valid_array[i] = 0;
            for(j=0; j<N; j=j+1) begin
                foo[j].bar.array[i] = 0;
            end
        end
    end
```

This is my generate block:

```
    genvar jj;
    generate
        for(jj = 0; jj < N; jj = jj + 1) begin : foo
            Memory_v3
            #(
                .ADDRESS_WIDTH(INDEX),
                .DATA_WIDTH(TAG)
            ) bar
            (
                .clock(clock),
                .we(we),
                .addr_a(addra),
                .addr_b(addrb),
                .din(din),
                .dout(dout)
            );
        end
    endgenerate
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that `foo` block gets resolved at compile time. So, the names like `foo[0]`, `foo[1]` are pre-generated and are compile-time names, they not work with dynamic index resolution at run-time. Therefore `foo[j]` will not work.

the solution in this case is to use another generate block to initialize them. Something like the following.

```
 generate
   for(jj = 0; jj < N; jj = jj + 1) begin : foo_init
      initial begin
         // initialization of arrays
         for(i=0; i<(2**7); i=i+1) begin
            foo[jj].bar.array[i] = 0;
         end
      end
   end
endgenerate
```

Same story is with array of instances.

```
FOO bar[3:0](); // array of instances

int i,j;
generate
   for(jj = 0; jj < 4; jj = jj + 1) begin : foo_init
      initial begin
         for(i=0; i<(2**7); i=i+1) begin
            bar[jj].array[i] = 0;
         end
      end
   end
endgenerate
```

BTW, in system verilog you can avoid using `generate/endgenerate` pairs: